# Store and display a path with a Space using Dir /b and user selection Batch File

Tags: batch-file, directory, spaces

I'm writing a bat file that finds all the folders and/or files in a directy and list them 1 going up some a user can select a folder or file.
The problem I'm having is when it echos each folder in the directory for a user to select it only shows the first part of the folder before the space.

I have a directory with folder in it that have spaces in their name.
Example:
"Folder" shows as "Folder"
"Folder" with spaces shows as "Folder"
"Another Folder" shows as "Another"

If you select a folder with a space you get an error saying "The system cannot find the path specified."

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Sets directory as Network Drive an "cd" into it.
pushd "\\network\some\directory\"

:loop

set count=0

:: Read in files
for /f %%x in ('dir /b') do (
set /a count=count+1
set choice[!count!]=%%x
)


echo Select one:

:: Print list of files
for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
 echo %%x] !choice[%%x]:%cd%\=!
 )
 echo.


 :: Retrieve User input
 set /p select=? 
 echo.


 :: Check if string contains ".bat"
 echo !choice[%select%]! |findstr ".bat" >nul && (
 echo Success
 ) || (
 cd !choice[%select%]!
 goto :loop
 )

 pause

 popd
```

I'm pretty sure I just need "" somewhere but I have been unable to figure it out.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to use the `DELIMS` options with the `FOR /F` command to tell the `FOR` command to not split up the output into multiple tokens.  Just add: `"delims="` to your `FOR /F` command.

Comment: `dir /b` doesn't contain the path, if you don't give a `/s`, so no need to remove `%cd%`. If you actually do a `dir /s /b`, you can get just the name.extension with `set choice[!count!]=%%~nxx`

Comment: Thank you squashman, it worked.  I cant believe i missed something so simple

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For not splitting the output of the `dir /b` command you should use the `delims` option. You can write:

```bat
for /f  "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b') do whatever you want
```

Hope this helps!